# Reducing the complexity of BFS in Java

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, shortest-path, maze

I'm trying to implement a solution for an algorithm problem where:

"given the map of the rectangular space where the sphere moves in, and your initial
location, your task is to compute the minimum number of moves it takes to reach the
hole which will take you home (it is not so much the rolling that upsets you, but the
bumping into things). Each location of the space is either empty, or it contains an
obstacle or the hole.
The sphere may only move through the empty locations, in the directions parallel
to the sides of the map. Once the sphere starts moving, it only stops when it hits an
obstacle or it falls through the hole. If the sphere falls off a side of the map, there is no
way of getting back on the map again and you will never get home."

```
static int bfs(char[][] map, int startRow, int startColumn, int holeRow, int holeColumn) {
        int rows = map.length;
        int columns = map[0].length;
        int[] dr = { -1, 0, 1, 0 };
        int[] dc = { 0, 1, 0, -1 };
    
        Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[rows][columns];
        queue.add(new int[] { startRow, startColumn, 0 });
        visited[startRow][startColumn] = true;
    
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            int[] current = queue.poll();
            int row = current[0];
            int col = current[1];
            int moves = current[2];
    
            if (row == holeRow && col == holeColumn)
                return moves;
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int newRow = row + dr[i];
                int newCol = col + dc[i];
    
                while (newRow >= 0 && newRow < rows && newCol >= 0 && newCol < columns && map[newRow][newCol] != 'O') {
                    if (newRow == holeRow && newCol == holeColumn)
                        return moves + 1;
                    newRow += dr[i];
                    newCol += dc[i];
                }
    
                newRow -= dr[i];
                newCol -= dc[i];
    
                if (!visited[newRow][newCol]) {
                    queue.add(new int[] { newRow, newCol, moves + 1 });
                    visited[newRow][newCol] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

And although the code I wrote is able to calculate output the results needed, it seems to be too slow since I get "Time Limit Exceeded" when testing it on the platform provided.

What can I do to reduce the complexity of this code? Is it even possible to have less loops?

```
Sample Input:
10 20 3
.....O..............
OOO.OO.OOOOOOOO.....
O.............O..OOO
O.O..O.............O
O.O..O........OOO..O
..O..O..........O..O
..O..OOOO.......O..O
..O..........H.....O
..O................O
..OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
8 1
8 5
1 10

Sample Output:
4
1
Stuck
```

I tried using directed graphs, it didn't help me, I tried checking the 4 directions with if's and it also helpful. So I'm not sure what I can do.

Comment: You left out a lot of important information from the question -- the part about the input format and constraints that explains why you're getting TLE.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may optimize by memorizing the previous move and only process orthogonal moves.

Then `current[3]` gives an index to the allowed move and a structure would contains the tables for each directions `{{2,3},{0,1},{2,3},{0,1},{0,1,2,3}}`. Here a dummy previous direction=4 will be used as the first previous direction and allow scanning all directions.

This would change the complexity only by a multiplier since trying the same direction and the opposite will give an already seen cell and won’t fill the queue.

Note: it appears that the edge are seen as wall when you want the move to be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

I think, when sphere hits the obstacle you need to save information about direction been chosen as well, not just obstacle coordinates.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] map = new char[][]{
            /*0*/".....O..............".toCharArray(),
            /*1*/"OOO.OO.OOOOOOOO.....".toCharArray(),
            /*2*/"O.............O..OOO".toCharArray(),
            /*3*/"O.O..O.............O".toCharArray(),
            /*4*/"O.O..O........OOO..O".toCharArray(),
            /*5*/"..O..O..........O..O".toCharArray(),
            /*6*/"..O..OOOO.......O..O".toCharArray(),
            /*7*/"..O..........H.....O".toCharArray(),
            /*8*/"..O................O".toCharArray(),
            /*9*/"..OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO".toCharArray(),
            /*    0123456789abcdefgijk  */
    };

    System.out.println(bfs(map, 7, 0));
    System.out.println(bfs(map, 7, 4));
    System.out.println(bfs(map, 0, 10));
    System.out.println(bfs(map, 0, 0));
    System.out.println(bfs(map, 9, 1));
    System.out.println(bfs(map, 8, 4));
    System.out.println(bfs(map, 2, 4));
}


static int bfs(char[][] map, int startRow, int startColumn) {
    int rows = map.length;
    int columns = map[0].length;

    int[][] seen = new int[rows][columns];

    int holeRow = -1;
    int holeColumn = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if ('H' == map[i][j]) {
                holeRow = i;
                holeColumn = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    int[] dr = {-1, 0, 1, 0};
    int[] dc = {0, 1, 0, -1};
    int[] pair = {2, 3, 0, 1};

    Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        queue.add(new int[]{startRow, startColumn, 0, i});
    }

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        int[] current = queue.poll();
        int row = current[0];
        int col = current[1];
        int moves = current[2];
        int dir = current[3];

        if (row == holeRow && col == holeColumn) {
            return moves;
        }

        int newRow = row + dr[dir];
        int newCol = col + dc[dir];
        while (true) {
            if (newRow < 0 || newRow >= rows || newCol < 0 || newCol >= columns) {
                // falls off a side
                break;
            }

            if (newRow == holeRow && newCol == holeColumn) {
                // falls through the hole
                return moves + 1;
            }

            if (map[newRow][newCol] != 'O') {
                // move forward
                newRow += dr[dir];
                newCol += dc[dir];
                continue;
            }

            // obstacle:
            //      move back and turn into
            //      perpendicular direction

            newRow -= dr[dir];
            newCol -= dc[dir];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int bit = 2 << i;
                if (i == dir || i == pair[dir]) {
                    seen[newRow][newCol] |= bit;
                }
                if ((seen[newRow][newCol] & bit) != bit) {
                    queue.add(new int[]{newRow, newCol, moves + 1, i});
                    seen[newRow][newCol] |= bit;
                }
            }

            break;

        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```