# Shortest Path DFS

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

Continuing my education of graph theory, I started to tackle the [Maze II problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/the-maze-ii/)

> There is a ball in a maze with empty spaces (represented as 0) and
> walls (represented as 1). The ball can go through the empty spaces by
> rolling up, down, left or right, but it won't stop rolling until
> hitting a wall. When the ball stops, it could choose the next
> direction.
>
> Given the m x n maze, the ball's start position and the destination,
> where start = [startrow, startcol] and destination = [destinationrow,
> destinationcol], return the shortest distance for the ball to stop at
> the destination. If the ball cannot stop at destination, return -1.
>
> The distance is the number of empty spaces traveled by the ball from
> the start position (excluded) to the destination (included).

To get my feet wet, I wrote an algorithm based on DFS to check each direction for each cell and continue in a depth first manner if possible to find "paths", each time keeping count of the number of steps. I have a global variable that checks if the current count is less and then replaces the value. However, my shortest path isn't always right. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? I do understand that BFS yields a shortest path but I have having trouble visualizing the BFS done in different directions.

Basically, I change direction only when I hit a wall and each time the count would start off with the count that the recursive function would have started with. As an example, running the algorithm below should produce a shortest path of 12 but my algorithm spits out 16

```
public class MazeII {
    int shortest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int[][] dirs = { { -1, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, -1 }, { 0, 1 } };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] maze = {{0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0},{1,1,0,1,1},{0,0,0,0,0}};
        int[] start = {0,4};
        int[] destination = {4,4};
        MazeII mii = new MazeII();
        System.out.println(mii.shortestDistance(maze, start, destination));
    }

    public int shortestDistance(int[][] maze, int[] start, int[] destination) {
        int count = 0;
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[maze.length][maze[0].length];
        dfs(maze, start[0], start[1], destination, visited, count);
        return shortest == Integer.MAX_VALUE? -1 : shortest;
        
    }
    
    private void dfs(int[][] maze, int i, int j, int[] destination, boolean[][]visited, int count) {
        if( visited[i][j]) {
            return;
        }
        if (i == destination[0] && j == destination[1]) {
            shortest = Math.min(shortest, count);
            return;
        }
        
        visited[i][j] = true;

        for (int[] dir : dirs) {
            int x = i;
            int y  = j;
            int newcount = count;
            while (x + dir[0] >= 0 && x + dir[0] < maze.length &&
                    y + dir[1] >= 0 && y + dir[1] < maze[0].length &&
                    maze[x + dir[0]][y + dir[1]] == 0) {
                x+=dir[0];
                y+=dir[1];
                newcount++;
            }
            dfs(maze, x , y, destination, visited, newcount);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your dfs is recursive.  Not a good idea.  You will run out of stack on any graph of a significant size.  Certainly you should not have so many parameters for a recursive function - you will run out of stack memory even faster then neccessary.

Comment: You should post a reproducible example - that means complete application code, the input that demos the problem and an explanation of how it differs from expected.

Comment: See [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Comment: But my code does not use Dijkstr's

Comment: In general, Dijkstra is used to solve mazes.  However, there is a wrinkle in this problem that make things more complicated "won't stop rolling until hitting a wall. "

Comment: Exactly! But thank you both for that tip...in general a dfs is slower but theoretically possible right?

Comment: I think that you will have to use A* for this, using Dijkstra as the heuristic to choose the next step.

Comment: @Spindoctor, `visited[i][j] = true;` - that seems to be a typical mistake: you are marking cell as visited before figuring out whether current path is optimal or not. [bfs solution is available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76084930/3426309)

Comment: Thanks are you suggesting moving the check for visited after the check for arrived at destination?

Comment: in your algo the purpose of `boolean[][] visited` array is to prevent infinite loops within single path, however, since that array is global, writing to it prevents your algo from considering other paths - you need at least set `visited[i][j]` to true after `for` loop, moreover you nowhere pay attention to direction in which you have seen the cell, so, `boolean[][] visited` is not a good structure there, `boolean[M][N][4] visited` seems to be more suitable. btw, after fixing that you will get TLE error

Comment: Besides the starting and ending grid squares, only the border grid squares matter, right (because your direction is otherwise completely fixed by what direction you were traveling from the last time you were on a border square)? With this, only `O(R + C)` nodes are needed that correspond to the border squares, where `R` and `C` are the number of rows and columns of the grid, respectively. Then, as mentioned previously, Dijkstra's Algorithm is appropriate for this problem, because the edges (the connections between nodes) are weighted (different distances) and positive.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov, I am not understanding. Can you give an example ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the modifications. What I understand now is I was doing dfs but it was a single path as I marked all visited as true but what you have done is for every change in direction, you treat it as a new path and all nodes are open to being visited again but due to a different direction. Is this the right interpretation?

Comment: "either different or more optimal"

Comment: thank you for helping using my logic and making the modifications, I have learned a lot by you taking the time to do this. really appreciate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what I was trying to explain in comments:

```java
public class MazeII {
    int shortest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int[][] dirs = {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] maze = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
        int[] start = {0, 4};
        int[] destination = {4, 4};
        MazeII mii = new MazeII();
        System.out.println(mii.shortestDistance(maze, start, destination));
    }

    public int shortestDistance(int[][] maze, int[] start, int[] destination) {
        int count = 0;
        boolean[][][] visited = new boolean[maze.length][maze[0].length][4];
        dfs(maze, start[0], start[1], destination, visited, count);
        return shortest == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? -1 : shortest;

    }

    private void dfs(int[][] maze, int i, int j, int[] destination, boolean[][][] visited, int count) {
        if (i == destination[0] && j == destination[1]) {
            shortest = Math.min(shortest, count);
            return;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < dirs.length; k++) {
            int[] dir = dirs[k];
            int x = i;
            int y = j;
            int newcount = count;
            while (x + dir[0] >= 0 && x + dir[0] < maze.length &&
                    y + dir[1] >= 0 && y + dir[1] < maze[0].length &&
                    maze[x + dir[0]][y + dir[1]] == 0) {
                x += dir[0];
                y += dir[1];
                newcount++;
            }
            if (!visited[x][y][k]) {
                visited[x][y][k] = true;
                dfs(maze, x, y, destination, visited, newcount);
                visited[x][y][k] = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, in order to make traversal algorithm more optimal, you need somehow eliminate sub-optimal paths, for example store distance from cell to the destination when particular direction has been chosen:

```java
public class MazeII {
    int shortest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int[][] dirs = {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] maze = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
        int[] start = {0, 4};
        int[] destination = {4, 4};
        MazeII mii = new MazeII();
        System.out.println(mii.shortestDistance(maze, start, destination));
    }

    public int shortestDistance(int[][] maze, int[] start, int[] destination) {
        int count = 0;
        int[][][] visited = new int[maze.length][maze[0].length][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maze[0].length; j++) {
                Arrays.fill(visited[i][j], Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            }
        }

        dfs(maze, start[0], start[1], destination, visited, count);
        return shortest == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? -1 : shortest;

    }

    private void dfs(int[][] maze, int i, int j, int[] destination, int[][][] visited, int count) {
        if (i == destination[0] && j == destination[1]) {
            shortest = Math.min(shortest, count);
            return;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < dirs.length; k++) {
            int[] dir = dirs[k];
            int x = i;
            int y = j;
            int newcount = count;
            while (x + dir[0] >= 0 && x + dir[0] < maze.length &&
                    y + dir[1] >= 0 && y + dir[1] < maze[0].length &&
                    maze[x + dir[0]][y + dir[1]] == 0) {
                x += dir[0];
                y += dir[1];
                newcount++;
            }
            if (newcount < visited[x][y][k]) {
                visited[x][y][k] = newcount;
                dfs(maze, x, y, destination, visited, newcount);
            }
        }
    }

}
```